# What is the best way to deal with analyzing commands from transaction results?

Tags: javascript, speech-to-text

To create custom commands - voice commands - we analyze the transaction results that are returned from the voice api and then take related action, if applicable.

Ex. User will say "New Paragraph" and that will trigger the action `createNewParagraph`

We've run into a few issues with this 'solution' that I am seeking to discuss. Firstly, we have to ensure we are comparing strings without case sensitivity, so 'new paragraph' 'New paragraph' and 'New paragraph' are equal; comparing and analyzing more than one string in this way - and taking related action - will equate to processing time and potential conflicts, slowing down the response and giving a poor experience to the user.

Secondly, when the defined 'command phrase' is part user's dictation, it triggers an action (when perhaps none was intended) ex.

```
let command = "Call Bob";
// user's transcription is "Yesterday I arrived to work and no one was 
// there so I had to CALL BOB to open the front door"
```

^^ This will trigger action `call(Bob)` (or whatever is defined)

(A silly example to try to demonstrate a problem we are workshopping)

How have you conquered these issues? What resources do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

It is called intent extraction. You can try [Rasa](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu) for that. For javascript there is something like 
[Compromise](https://github.com/spencermountain/compromise)